# Solid-blocking DIV's using javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make solid blocks out of DIVs side by side horizontally & vertically & I've managed to do that while div's have the same height. But when a div has bigger height and width it'll become under another divs while those divs should be beside & under it. This is a sample of the problem (http://givemeaudience.com/test.html) & below is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Test</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;">
<style>
    body{margin:0px;padding:0px;font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;font-size:12px;}
    #container{position:relative;}
    #container .box{width:143px;height:143px;background:#eee;padding:5px;position:absolute;}
    #container .s21{width:303px;}
    #container .s32{width:463px;height:303px;background:#F60;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function relocate(){
        var browserWidth = $(window).width();
        var defaultWidth = 160;
        var yPos = 7;
        var xPos = 7;
        $('.box').each(function(i, obj) {
            elementWidth = $(this).width();

            if(xPos + elementWidth > browserWidth){
                yPos = yPos + 160;
                xPos = 7;
            }
            $(this).css('top',yPos+'px');
            $(this).css('left',xPos+'px');

            xPos = xPos + 17 + $(this).width();
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        relocate();
        $(window).resize(function() {
            relocate();
        });
    });
</script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="container">
<div class="box" id="">
    Test
</div>
<div class="box" id="">
    Test
</div>
<div class="box" id="">
    Test
</div>
<div class="box" id="">
    Test
</div>
<div class="box s32" id="">
    Test
</div>
<div class="box" id="">
    Test
</div>
<div class="box" id="">
    Test
</div>
<div class="box" id="">
    Test
</div>
<div class="box" id="">
    Test
</div>
<div class="box" id="">
    Test
</div>
<div class="box" id="">
    Test
</div>
<div class="box" id="">
    Test
</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give a better explanation (perhaps with a picture) of what you would like to happen? I don't follow your explanation. Also, the demo hyperlink didn't work for me.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for this: http://masonry.desandro.com/.

Answer (score 0):

If You want to compact your .box`es within #container, better solution - display them as "inline-block" and float as you want (to the left or to the right). But you should know, that order of blocks should be specialized before.
Here the simple CSS box alignment:

```
#container {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.box {
    white-space: auto;        
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    float:left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/iegik/DBkXU/

Whatever, If you want reorder them instantly, sizes of boxes should be typically - predefined widths and heights (for example, XS, S, M, L, XL, XXL - sizes). Then place them in matrix:

```
[ 2x1,  0,  1x2, 1x3 ],
[ 1x1, 1x2,  0,   0  ],
[ 1x1,  0,  1x1,  0  ]
```

Comment: blocks_in_row = row_width / block_width;